# Search DataGridView for duplicates

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code to find duplicate values in DataGridView and mark them with different colors.

```
var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Reverse().Skip(1); 
var dupRos = rows.GroupBy(r => r.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString()).Where(g => 
g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(r => r.ToList());
foreach (var r in dupRos)
{
    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
}
foreach (var r in rows.Except(dupRos))
{
    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
}
```

The code works fine.
I have changed the code so it will write in the second column the word Unique or Duplicate and a counter number for the duplicate cells.

```
int counter = 1;
var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Reverse().Skip(1); 
//ignore the last empty line
var dupRos = rows.GroupBy(r => r.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString()).Where(g => 
g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(r => r.ToList());
foreach (var r in dupRos)
{
    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
    r.Cells["Time"].Value = "Dup" + counter;
    counter++;
}
foreach (var r in rows.Except(dupRos))
{
    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
    r.Cells["Time"].Value = "Unick";
}
```

My problem is that the counter continues to count for all the duplicate groups and not reset itself every time its start with a different group of duplicate values.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one. If it works you can replace string type for lastDupRowDate with actual date type.

```
int counter = 1;
var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Reverse().Skip(1); 
//ignore the last empty line
var dupRos = rows.GroupBy(r => r.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString()).Where(g => 
g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(r => r.ToList());
string lastDupRowDate = null;
foreach (var r in dupRos)
{
    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
    counter = lastDupRowDate == r.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString() ? count + 1 : 1;
    lastDupRowDate = r.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString();
    r.Cells["Time"].Value = "Dup" + counter;
}
foreach (var r in rows.Except(dupRos))
{
    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
    r.Cells["Time"].Value = "Unick";
}
```